# MSVS 2015: is there a way to view the unadulterated assembly in the disassembly window?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, disassembly

for example, as I'm going through some disassembly, I see the line:

```
00007FF967907039 66 0F 6F 44 24 60    movdqa      xmm0,xmmword ptr [chain0]
```

(having show byte code and show address enabled).  Presumably, this is telling me that it's loading into xmm0 what's stored in the memory address it has associated with my source code local variable, chain0, which is useful for me, but it'd also be convenient for me to be able to see the unadulterated assembly, so...

```
xmmword ptr [chain0]
```

would instead be

```
xmmword ptr [rax]
```

or

```
xmmword ptr [150h]
```

or whatever it would happen to be.  Is there any setting that would allow me to conveniently do that?

Comment: The same way you got the code bytes to show up.  Right-click the disassembly window again, now untick the "Show Symbol Names" option.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  Pretty obvious in hindsight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hans Passant mentioned, right-clicking in the disassembly window and unchecking "Show Symbol Names" does it.